# Visual Studio, Python, Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-953alcay\rpy2\

Tags: python, r, visual-studio

I am trying to install **rpy2** in Visual Studio Professional 2017 version 15.8.2, in Python 3.6, and I get the *egg_info* error seen below.

I have searched for similar problems and followed their suggestions without luck

- I am running Visual Studio as administrator
- I have made sure that **pip** (version 18.0) and **setuptools** (version 40.2.0) are up to date

I am running windows 10 and out of idears

```
    ----- Installing 'rpy2' -----
Collecting rpy2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f1/98/c7652cc9d7fc0afce74d2c30a52b9c9ac391713a63d037e4ab8feb56c530/rpy2-2.9.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) -- "Feather Spray"
    Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
    Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

    R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
    You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
    GNU General Public License versions 2 or 3.
    For more information about these matters see
    http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.

    R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) -- "Feather Spray"
    C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-35~1.1\bin\x64\R CMD config --ldflags
    'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\ERIKWA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-953alcay\rpy2\setup.py", line 374, in <module>
        ri_ext = getRinterface_ext()
      File "C:\Users\ERIKWA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-953alcay\rpy2\setup.py", line 269, in getRinterface_ext
        ldf = shlex.split(' '.join(rexec.cmd_config('--ldflags')))
      File "C:\Users\ERIKWA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-953alcay\rpy2\setup.py", line 222, in cmd_config
        universal_newlines = True)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
        **kwargs).stdout
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 418, in run
        output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('C:\\PROGRA~1\\R\\R-35~1.1\\bin\\x64\\R', 'CMD', 'config', '--ldflags')' returned non-zero exit status 1.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ERIKWA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-953alcay\rpy2\
----- Failed to install 'rpy2' -----
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't have sh command, you just need to install something like Cygwin to solve this